# interface is down but netstat still shows the connection established?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a c, c++ program. which is using `TCP` sockets.

when i make my interface down using `ifdown`. network interface goes down.
but when i see the `netstat` there it still shows the connection state is `established` between client and server.

I want to close my socket immediately as interface is down. I know if i will reduce `keep-alive time` it may help.

But i want to know if there is any other better way to do this.

Does any `signal` gets generated when interface is down?

OR is there anything else which can tell my application that interface is down so that i can close my socket?

netstat -o output:-

```
> tcp        0      0 172.16.12.51:9999           172.16.12.51:38117     ESTABLISHED 3130/./DiaServertD  off (0.00/0/0)

> tcp        0      0 172.16.12.51:38117          172.16.12.51:9999     ESTABLISHED 3177/./sampleGxClie off (0.00/0/0)
```

Comment: "*... still shows the connection state is established*" What does netstat **exactly** tell you?

Comment: @alk edited the question with netstat o/p for both server and client.

Comment: It can take up to two minutes for a connection to be deemed dead...

Comment: Are you sure that the network interface is actually down? There is an old discussion on how ifdown doesn't always work as expected. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=900804

Comment: Right, also ifconfig wlan0 down for example does not guarantee to keep the shut down device shut down, if another process ( wicd-demon for example ) also uses this device. It immediately will turn it on again.

Comment: @Abhinav, yes it is down i can see it when i do ifconfig.